# Как правильно вставить значение из json в тег?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Приходит json. И в html разметке уже есть 5 тегов Нужно чтоб каждое значение записалось в каждый тег по порядку. Например :`<h1> Денис</h1> , <h1>Николай</h1> ,<h1> Владислав</h1> ,<h1> Евгений</h1> , <h1>Александр</h1>` .

Пробовал через apend() но у меня почему - то в усе теги записывает ток последний элемент.

```
    $('h1').each(function(index, value){
        var name = value[index].name;
        $(this).text(name);
      });
```

вот сам json:

```
{
 "1": {
     "name": "Денис"
 },
 "2": {
     "name": "Николай"
 },
 "3": {
     "name": "Владислав"
 },
 "4": {
     "name": "Евгений"
 },
 "5": {
     "name": "Александр"
 }
}
```

Как синтаксически верно записать такой обход элементов ?

Comment: Приведите ваш javascript, иначе непонятно что у вас не так

Comment: Покажите HTML, пожалуйста

Comment: ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich здесь Angular не используется

Comment: @naXa можно так же написать скриптик по атрибуту поиск ng-repeat разбор и вставка такого же элемента. Тогда просто подключая скрипт сможете строить аналогичные конструкции.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, зачем? Или вы умеете мыслить только в категориях Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните теги в `<div class="top-html-tag"></div>`. Пройдитесь по именам циклом и используйте функции [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference):

```
var names = document.getElementsByClassName("top-html-tag")[0].childNodes;
var items = json.items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length && i < names.length; ++i) {
    names[i].innerHTML = items[i].name;
}
```

`getElementsByClassName` не работает в IE ниже 9 версии. Если вы хотите поддерживать старые браузеры, лучше используйте jQuery.

Comment: Ваш , метод создает разметку , а как сделать чтоб вставлялось в уже существующие теги ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999 а сейчас? Не уверен, что код работает, но, надеюсь, идея ясна.